# OPEN_CV ERROR not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: opencv, ide, spyder

```
for, 
 image, contours, hierarchy =  cv2.findContours(erosion,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

It is showing this error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Python version: 3.7.2
OpenCV version: 4.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma after the for loop, i'm surprised you are not getting  syntax error from that. I'm not sure what you need a for loop there in the first place. If you want to iterate over each of the values that return from findContours do that after you have assigned the values to a variable. It looks like you don't pass the image as one of the values to unpack. Try rewriting the line as follows:
[From the docs](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/contours.py)

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(erosion,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Assuming erosion is the name of the image. The reason why you are getting that error is because you are assigning 3 variables to a function and only outputs 2 (contours and the hierarchy). So python is expecting 3 outputs from findContours but only returning two, thus leading to the error you are getting.

Comment: thank you so much this helped me, i'm getting expected output :)                                by the way are you Japanese???

Comment: Nope :). Mark as the answer is it has been helpful so others know also!